# Nonequality for Javascript String and Variable

Tags: node.js, string, variables, debugging, equality

I'm trying to check whether an array, called `ruleFolderNames`, contains a string, using the `.includes()` Javascript method. The string I am checking is `"Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services"`.

```
ruleFolderNames.includes("Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services"); // true
```

However, I'm not typing the string directly, I'm using a variable (called `department`). I've found that the `department` variable is **not** equal to the first item in the array, `Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services`, *even though they appear to be the same*.

Here are the `console.log` statements:

```
    ruleFolderNames[0]; // Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services
    typeof ruleFolderNames[0]; // string

    department; // Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services
    typeof department; // string
```

But in fact, the variable `department` is not equal to the string I'm searching for.

```
department == "Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services" // OUTPUTS FALSE!!!
```

I've included the link to my full Github [repository](https://github.com/KingOfCramers/federal-register-searcher) if that's useful, the bug is contained on line 36 of [this](https://github.com/KingOfCramers/federal-register-searcher/blob/master/firebase/index.js) file.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question itself to answer, but I would start at checking the `.length` of each string, and if that doesn't pan out, compare the charCodes of each string. `for (const letter of department) console.log(letter.charCodeAt(0));` Find the first that doesn't match (or use a `for` loop and do something when `department[i] !== ruleFolderNames[0][i]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't have the actual data ourselves to debug, we can't tell you exactly what difference there is.  Here are a number of things to look for:

1. Check the length of both strings to see if there might be a difference in leading or trailing whitespace that isn't obvious in the console.  You can also output in the console with quotes surrounding it to see exactly what might be on the start or end such as `` console.log(`'${department}'`) `` and `` ruleFolderNames.forEach(item => console.log(`'${item}'`)) ``.
2. White space characters might be different, but look like regular whitespace in the console.  If you suspect the difference is in the department variable (which it appears it is), then you can normalize the whitespace with `department.replace(/\s/g, " ")` which converts all regex whitespace characters to a single space.
3. There could be some character that looks similar, but is actually a different char code.

Since you say that `department == "Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services"` is false, I'd suggest the following debug code (with your `department` variable passed to `testStr()`:

```js
function testStr(testVal, targetStr) {
        console.log("-------------");
        if (testVal === targetStr) {
            console.log("two strings are the same");
            return;
        } 
        if (testVal.length !== targetStr.length) {
            console.log("two strings are different length");
            if (testVal.trim() === targetStr) {
                console.log("Found it: testVal.trim() === targetStr");
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("testVal.trim() !== targetStr, trimming whitespace off ends is not enough");
            }
            testVal = testVal.trim();
        }
        if (testVal.replace(/\s/g, " ") === targetStr) {
            console.log("replacing whitespace makes a match")
            return;
        }
        // still no match, so lets output each separate character as a char code
        // to manually see what's different
        console.log("testVal = ", testVal.split("").map(item => item.charCodeAt(0)).join(","));
        console.log("targetStr = ", targetStr.split("").map(item => item.charCodeAt(0)).join(","));
    }
    
    const testValues = [
        " Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services",  // leading whitespace
        "Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services ",  // trailing whitespace
        "Centers\tFor Medicare & Medicaid Services",  // tab for whitespace
        "C℮nters For Medicare & Medicaid Services",   // odd first e in Centers
        "Cënters For Medicare & Medicaid Services"    // odd first e in Centers
    ];

    for (let t of testValues) {
       testStr(t, "Centers For Medicare & Medicaid Services");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. There was a trailing white space in the variable that I couldn't see.